# Start window 64 bit explorer.exe from 32 bit installer

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, explorer, installanywhere

My Question: I need to kill the explore.exe and start the explorer.exe on 64 bit machine using 32 bit installer. If i created the batch file and double click on the batch file then it work fine but when i integrate in installer, it failed.

I execute below mentioned command but not able to succeed.

When i executed the below command, it kill the task bar and create the explorer.exe but not shown the taskbar.

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
cd C:\Windows\Sysnative 
start /B explorer.exe
```

When i executed the below command, it kill the task bar and create the explorer.exe but shown the taskbar and hang the installer.

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
%systemroot%\sysnative\cmd.exe /c start /B explorer.exe
```

Please suggest me how solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I didn't get your point. Please provide a better solution for this problem.